# How to split midi file based on notes pitch using python?

Tags: python, audio, midi, audio-processing, music21

How can I split midi files based on their pitch using python? I tried the music21 library, but I don't really know how this works...

Comment: What do you mean by "split on pitch"?

Comment: For example, when I have a lower c and a higher c it should be split up into two .mid files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
import pretty_midi
import copy

pitch_cutoff = 65

mid = pretty_midi.PrettyMIDI('my_file.mid')
low_notes = copy.deepcopy(mid)
high_notes = copy.deepcopy(mid)

for instrument in low_notes.instruments:
    for note in instrument.notes:
        if note.pitch > pitch_cutoff:
            note.velocity = 0

for instrument in high_notes.instruments:
    for note in instrument.notes:
        if note.pitch < pitch_cutoff:
            note.velocity = 0

low_notes.write("low_notes.mid")
high_notes.write("high_notes.mid")
```

it uses the `pretty_midi` module to split a midi file into two different files.  The file called "high_notes.mid" will only have notes above what you set the `pitch_cutoff` variable to, and "low_notes.mid" will only have notes below that.  Just change "my_file.mid" to whatever the name of your file is and try it out.  Let me know if you have any questions.